# Prevenir vários submit via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

Estou fazendo um formulário com validações do abide (Foundation 6) e não estou conseguindo prevenir vários submit's.

Acontece o seguinte: Quando é clicado no botão Submit do formulário a seguinte função entra em ação.

```
$('#form-principal').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // sem o formvalid.zf.abide do foundation, o submit acontece com campos inválidos
  $(this).on('formvalid.zf.abide', function () {
        alert('Submitou');
  });
});
```

O problema é o seguinte: Quando é clicado no botão submit, o Abide reclama do campo inválido, até ai tudo bem, o usuário vai e corrigi o campo para o abide validar corretamente e clica novamente no Submit, e então, a função acima "submita" 2x em um único clique. E assim por diante, por exemplo: se clicar 3x no submit o Abide não validar as 3x, na 4° vez se estiver tudo certo, o submit será feito 4x em um único clique.

Alguma ideia para prevenir esses vários submit's?

HTML:

```
<form id="form-principal" method="post">
  <label>Teste
    <input type="text" name="teste" required>
  </label>
  <button>
    Vai filhão
  </button>
</form>

<script>
  // inicia o Foundation
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).foundation();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que a cada submit do seu `#form-principal` você adiciona um novo listener de evento no `formvalid.zf.abide`. Então ele vai responder as `N` vezes que você ja submitou o `#form-principal`.

Se realmente for necessário você adicionar o evento no `formvalid.zf.abide` apenas quando fizer o submit do `#form-principal`, retire o evento anterior e adicione de novo:

```
$('#form-principal').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).off('formvalid.zf.abide');
  $(this).on('formvalid.zf.abide', function () {
        alert('Submitou');
  });
});
```

Sugiro você habilitar o botão de submeter o form dentro do evento que valida o `#form-principal`:

```
$(document)
  .on('forminvalid.zf.abide', function () {
    $('#form-principal input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
  })
  .on('formvalid.zf.abide', function () {
    $('#form-principal input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
  });
$('#form-principal').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: usei com o $(this).off('formvalid.zf.abide'); e deu certo! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eu desabilitaria o botão depois que o usuário clicasse

//JavaScript

document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;

Ou em Jquery

$("button").prop("disabled",true);

Comment: O disabled eu faço no inicio do programa original, o que acontece é quando o form é "submitado", ele considera as tentativas que fiz anterior quee não deram certo. Ou seja, há vezes que clico 1x no botão submit e o jQuery manda o submit 3x